# Meta programing of DolphinDB: how to pass a function in sqlCol

Tags: sql, metaprogramming, dolphindb

I’m trying something with the function `sqlUpdate` and the where condition that I passed in is generated with the metaprogramming technique. I got an error:

```
::evaluate(sqlUpdate(t1, u, , w)) => Unrecognized column name date(date)
```

Here’s my full script:

```
t1=table(`A`A`B`B as symbol, 2021.04.15 2021.04.16 2021.04.15 2021.04.16 as date, 12 13 21 22 as price)
updCol = `price
dateCol = `date
u = sqlColAlias( expr(sqlCol(updCol), +, -1) , updCol )
w = expr(sqlCol("date("+dateCol+")"), ==, 2021.04.15)
sqlUpdate(table=t1 ,updates=u ,where = w).eval()
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute `sqlCol("date("+dateCol+")")` independently, the result is:

```
< date(date) >
```

It may seem correct at first glance. However, as the first argument of `sqlCol` is a column, the whole thing `date(date)` will be parsed as a column name.

Remember that the second argument of `sqlCol` is a function. So we can write `sqlCol(dateCol,date)`. In this way, “date“ will be recognized as a column name and the second argument is treated as the function to be applied to the “date“ column.

The parsing result:

```
< date(date) as date >
```

Full script:

```
t1=table(`A`A`B`B as symbol, 2021.04.15 2021.04.16 2021.04.15 2021.04.16 as date, 12 13 21 22 as price)
updCol = `price
dateCol = `date
u = sqlColAlias( expr(sqlCol(updCol), +, -1) , updCol )
w = expr(sqlCol(dateCol, date), ==, 2021.04.15)
sqlUpdate(table=t1 ,updates=u ,where = w).eval()
```